# How to embed a Powerpoint in html with some constraints listed inside

Tags: html, powerpoint

I am trying to embed a company PowerPoint presentation into an intranet website and am having some issues. I tried converting to pdf and embedding it with this html:

```
<object data="myFile.pdf" type="application/pdf" width='100%' height="8000px">
    <p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.You can <a href="myFile.pdf">click here to
        download the PDF file.</a></p>
</object>
```

but there is a link in the ppt that stops linking correctly somehow. So I tried converting to an htm page and doing a javascript redirect to that page but I get a page that just says my browser doesnt have the correct plugin to open the pdf.

And unfortunately, being a company project, we aren't allowed to use commercially available cloud storage (ie: Google Docs, Onedrive, etc.) for security and privacy purposes. Are there other ways to embed the powerpoint, not using 3rd party software?

Comment: So put the ppt/pdf into the same storage as the html file - I don't see any problems

Comment: @Arusekk I think he wants to embed it on the page, so the browser displays it.

Comment: @Arusekk, it is in the same directory. 19greg96, you are correct

Comment: With my Firefox 24.6.0 your code works perfectly

Comment: @Arusekk he said his ppt converted to pdf is malformed: "but there is a link in the ppt that stops linking correctly somehow" The code he posted does indeed work

Comment: Yeah it works, but there is a link that opens an excel page that was in the powerpoint, and it works both in the offline powerpoint and pdf. but if you try to open it online, it opens a strange directory view in the browser

Comment: Because browsers have just strange pdf viewers - there is no better way to embed ppt in a webpage; BTW try to open pdf offline using browser (enter file://C:/users/me/and/so/on/file.pdf or for non-windows file:///path/to/file.pdf into your address bar in browser)